# B-Tree in TikZ without root node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees

I'm trying to reproduce the following tree structure with Tikz:[image]

---

Following several questions here I got the following snippet, which *almost* does the job, except for the fact that I am **not** able to remove the root node. In the followingm, the snippet and  my temporary solution.

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{bplus}=[rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal,draw]
    \tikzstyle{every node}=[bplus]
    \tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=90mm]
    \tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=25mm]
    \node {U} [->]
      child {node {A \nodepart{two} B \nodepart{three} C \nodepart{four}}
        child {node {D \nodepart{two} E \nodepart{three} F \nodepart{four} G}}
        child {node {H \nodepart{two} I \nodepart{three} J \nodepart{four} K}}    
        child {node {L \nodepart{two} M \nodepart{three} N  \nodepart{four}}}    
      } 
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

*How can I remove the root node and the arrow?*

[image]

Comment: Welcome. // Can you please turn this code snippet, which can't be compiled, into a MWE, e.g. this way: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 ? Thank you

Comment: Just don't draw first node in the tree. By this will the second become root node,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

May I suggest using `forest` instead of the base TikZ tree methods. There are many advantages to using `forest` for trees over other methods:

- much more compact syntax (labelled bracketting)
- automatic packing of nodes so that they will not overlap
- generally more compact trees

Here's your tree using it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\tikzset{bplus/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal,draw}}


\begin{document}
\begin{forest}for tree={bplus, edge={->},l sep=1cm}
[{A \nodepart{two} B \nodepart{three} C \nodepart{four}}
    [{D \nodepart{two} E \nodepart{three} F \nodepart{four} G}]
    [{H \nodepart{two} I \nodepart{three} J \nodepart{four} K}]
    [{L \nodepart{two} M \nodepart{three} N  \nodepart{four}}]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Also, the `\tikzstyle` command is deprecated. You should use instead `\tikzset` as in this example.

If you do want to use the base methods, then you need to remove the U node from your code:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style=bplus,level 1/.style={sibling distance=25mm},->]
      \node {A \nodepart{two} B \nodepart{three} C \nodepart{four}}
        child {node {D \nodepart{two} E \nodepart{three} F \nodepart{four} G}}
        child {node {H \nodepart{two} I \nodepart{three} J \nodepart{four} K}}    
        child {node {L \nodepart{two} M \nodepart{three} N  \nodepart{four}}}     
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Inspired by Zarko's simplification of the multipart node input (which is quite wordy), here's another version of that command which takes a comma separated list instead.  You may also want to incorporate their format for the nodes, which makes them uniform size.

To accommodate having each branch project from a particular cell of the parent, I've added an `multi edge` style to specify which specific node part of the parent you want that edge to project from. If you always want the nodes to map 1:1 from node parts to sequence of daughters, then you can simply use the `auto edge` style which does this automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\tikzset{bplus/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal,text width=1em, text centered, inner xsep=2pt,draw}}

\forestset{multi edge/.style={edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (!u.#1 south)--(.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};}},
auto edge/.style={for tree={edge path={\noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}] (!u.\getnode{\forestoption{n}} south)--(.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};}}
}}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_tree_node_seq
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \c_node_names_seq {one,two,three,four}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mpn}{m}{
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tree_node_seq {#1}
    \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l_tree_node_seq { 
        \nodepart{\getnode {##1}} {##2}
    }
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\getnode}{m}{\seq_item:Nn \c_node_names_seq {#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff  

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}for tree={bplus, auto edge,edge={->},l sep=1cm}
[\mpn{A,B,C,D}
    [\mpn{D,E,F,G}]
    [\mpn{H,I,J,K}]
    [\mpn{L,M,N},multi edge=four]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have one last question actually: in all the results, I'd like the first arrow from the left to emanate from A, the second from B and the last one from C. Is there a way to impose this?

Comment: @VoB Yes, I've added a style that allows you to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Small variation of the nice @Alan Munn answer (+1): shorter code for nodes contents and wee bit nicer formatted multi part nodes:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                shapes.multipart}
\newcommand\mpn[4]{\nodepart{one}   #1
                   \nodepart{two}   #2
                   \nodepart{three} #3
                   \nodepart{four}  #4}


\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
    rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal, 
    rectangle split parts=4,
    text width=1em, text centered, inner xsep=2pt,
    draw,
    edge = {semithick, -Straight Barb},
    l sep=12mm,
    s sep= 2mm,
            }
[\mpn{A}{B}{C}{ }
    [\mpn{D}{E}{F}{G}]
    [\mpn{H}{I}{J}{K}]
    [\mpn{L}{M}{N}{ }]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
Combining of the  @Alan Munn code for forming list of forest nodes contents but with  formatting of tree as i use in my original answer:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                shapes.multipart}

\ExplSyntaxOn   % proposed by Alan Mun
\seq_new:N \l_tree_node_seq
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \c_node_names_seq {one,two,three,four}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mpn}{m}{
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tree_node_seq {#1}
    \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l_tree_node_seq {
        \nodepart{\seq_item:Nn \c_node_names_seq {##1}} {##2}
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
    rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal,   % <---
    text width=1em, text centered, inner xsep=2pt, % <---
    draw,
    edge = {semithick, -Straight Barb},
    l sep=12mm,
    s sep= 2mm,
            }
[\mpn{A,B,C,~} % <---
    [\mpn{D,E,F,G}]
    [\mpn{H,I,J,K}]
    [\mpn{L,M,N,~}] % <---
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before!

Answer (score 4):

I'd make greater use of `forest`'s own facilities to shorten the code and simplify the syntax. I present two solutions. The first utilises `forest`'s builtin support for `tabular`s. This is the simplest. The second utilises `split option` to allow a simple, colon-separated input syntax for specifying the content of a multipart node. This is a bit more elaborate, but still easily accomplished with `forest`'s own processing facilities, and produces a more aesthetically pleasing result.

### Method 1 (Simpler, Not-Quite-As-Pretty)

`forest` has built-in support for `tabulars`, so I would leverage this capability. This code is derived from [Alan Munn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703663/). This makes it possible to use the familiar syntax used to define `tabular` rows to separate the different parts of each node in the tree.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703670/ addaswyd o ateb Alun Munn: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703663/
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{%
  bplus/.style={%
    align={|c|c|c|c|},
    before typesetting nodes={%
      content={\hline ##1\\\hline},
    },
  },
}


\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={bplus, edge={->},l sep'=1cm}
  [A & B & C &
    [D & E & F & G]
    [H & I & J & K,calign with current edge]
    [L & M & N  &]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabular nodes]

### Method 2 (Prettier, Slightly-More-Complex)

Since these do not look quite so nice as the multipart nodes, it may be worth noting that you can use this style with a simplified syntax just by utilising `forest`'s `split option`. I don't like using a comma to separate within `forest` nodes because I then have to keep track of the `{` and `}`. Instead, I'd recommend picking some other punctuation mark which doesn't occur in your nodes themselves and isn't treated specially by Ti*k*Z or `forest`. This example uses a colon, but you do pick something else if your tree contains colons else you'll be back to needing additional brace groups.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703670/ addaswyd o ateb Alun Munn: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703663/
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{%
  bplus/.style={%
    draw,
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split horizontal,
    before typesetting nodes={%
      split option={content}{:}{content',temptoksb,temptoksc,temptoksd},
      content+={\nodepart{two}},
      content+/.register=temptoksb,
      content+={\nodepart{three}},
      content+/.register=temptoksc,
      content+={\nodepart{four}},
      content+/.register=temptoksd,
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={bplus, edge={->},l sep'=1cm}
  [A:B:C:
    [D:E:F:G]
    [H:I:J:K, calign with current edge]
    [L:M:N:]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: multipart nodes using forest's split option for simplified syntax]

This can be modified in various ways e.g. to accommodate edges from different parts of the parent and/or child nodes.

[image: custom anchors for edges]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703670/ addaswyd o ateb Alun Munn: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703663/
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \bplus_anchor:n
{
  \int_case:nn { #1 }
  {
    { 1 } { one }
    { 2 } { two }
    { 3 } { three }
    { 4 } { four }
  }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \bplus_anchor:n { o }
\cs_new_eq:NN \bplusanchor \bplus_anchor:o 
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{%
  edge from/.style args={#1 to #2}{%
    edge path'={(!u.#1) -- (.#2)},
  },
  bplus/.style={%
    draw,
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split horizontal,
    child anchor=north,
    edge from/.process={Ow+ow{n}{\bplusanchor{##1}}{##1 south to child anchor}},
    text width=1em,
    /tikz/align=center,
    before typesetting nodes={%
      split option={content}{:}{content',temptoksb,temptoksc,temptoksd},
      content+={\nodepart{two}},
      content+/.register=temptoksb,
      content+={\nodepart{three}},
      content+/.register=temptoksc,
      content+={\nodepart{four}},
      content+/.register=temptoksd,
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={bplus, edge={->},l sep'=1cm}
  [A:B:C:
    [D:E:F:G]
    [H:I:J:K, child anchor=two north]
    [L:M:N:,edge from=four south to three north ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Personally, I'd probably use the first method because multipart nodes behave slightly oddly in some cases. But provided you're not doing anything further complicated, the multipart approaches definitely have a neater, more symmetric look.